# Regexp capture groups with common chars

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match all groups matching regex in a sentence but these groups have common characters in the sentence.
I'm facing this issue :
Exemple, in this sentence :

> A + B + C + D

I would like to catpure :

```
A + B
```

then

```
B + C
```

then

```
C + D
```

With java.utils.regex.Matcher.find (with pattern `([A-Z] \+ [A-Z])` [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Cdytsh/1))
It begins matching next group only after the last matched character so i'm matching only A + B then C + D.

Is there any way to do this with regex ?

Comment: Before we suggest any solutions post all requirements which we should know about input. Otherwise we will need to change our idea each time you decide to tell us more about each separate requirement.

Comment: For now one of ideas would be matching one part (A + ) and using look-ahead to capture another (B). How to write it depends on actual data format.

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo for your answer !
There is no special data format. After that, I just want to associate A to B then B to C then C to D in a Map.
The issue is that with the look-ahead if I'm not mistaken the B is not in a group in the first match.

Comment: True, look-ahead doesn't create group, but it doesn't mean we can't put capturing group there explicitly. So you could create regex like `[A-Z]\s\+\s(?=([A-Z]))` and then get `group(0)` which is match from `[A-Z]\s\+\s` and then `group(1)` which will hold `([A-Z])` from look-ahead.

Comment: Or, you could do it all at once `(?=(A + B))A` and move on to more stuff ..

Comment: Ok perfect thanks a lot ! I'm now able to associate each pairs like this https://regex101.com/r/Bgm2j0/1/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd match both inside a lookahead, then consume 1.

Find globally `(?=([A-Z]\s*\+\s*[A-Z]))[A-Z]`
Print group 1 each match or just get an array.

Overlaps work by match vs. consumption.
Match more than you need inside an assertion, then consume less.
Consumption repositions the start of the next match.

This process makes it overlap.

Expanded

```
 (?=
      ( [A-Z] \s* \+ \s* [A-Z] )    # (1)
 )
 [A-Z]
```

Matches

```
  **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 5 ) 
 A + B  
  **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 4 , len 5 ) 
 B + C  
  **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 8 , len 5 ) 
 C + D
```

Comment: What is the last `[A-Z]`?  `"(?=([A-Z]\\s*\\+\\s*[A-Z]))"` also works.

Comment: @saka1029 - Yes. What you've found is something called _bump along_. If a regex engine matches a zero width assertion and nothing is consumed (ie. the last `[A-Z]`) it automatically increments the current position by 1 character. So, this `(?=(.))` used against this `1234` will find 4 matches. The reality is that `[A-Z]` can be a big sub-expression that may have natural length > 1. In this case you'd need to consume it directly so it doesn't get trapped in +1 position for the next match. That is of course if `[A-Z]` is your unit.

Comment: @saka1029 - Example https://regex101.com/r/Bgm2j0/2 as opposed to this https://regex101.com/r/Bgm2j0/3

Comment: Thanks!  In this case, it is necessary to add `[A-Z]+` to the end.